# Close Vs Closed and Open Vs. Opened

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Which **board** is proper to describe **the state of any shop/restaurant?**

For instance,

> A restaurant with the board **Close** OR **Closed**? 
>   A restaurant with the board **Open** OR **Opened**?

Well, if I think **'closed' is used when the restaurant is permanently or temporarily closed for more than a day (say for holidays or renovation)**, what about the conversation mentioned below? It takes *-ed* even for that day!

> *"Hey Mike, I forgot my specs at home. Do you see the restaurant there at distance? Is it open?*
>   *"Yeah, I do see. But it's **closed.***

I think open/opened or close/closed here is **not a verb**. If it isn't, then what is it in those examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many businesses have signs saying **open** or **closed**.

When a business is **open**, it is ready to serve customers, and the doors are probably unlocked.
When a business is **closed**, it is not ready to serve customers, and the doors are likely locked.

Note that **closed** doesn't imply anything about when they'll open again.  They may never open again, or they may open in five minutes.  Many businesses post schedules on doors or windows saying when they'll be open or closed.

Both words are adjectives; [see Language Log for details](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005503.html) on why *open* and *closed* are in opposition.

Comment: What about a board of the restaurant stating 'close'? Also, if the restaurant board reads 'close', do we **say** that the restaurant is **closed?**

Comment: @MaulikV I've never seen a sign saying "close".  If I did, I'd assume that whoever wrote the sign made a mistake.

Comment: @snailboat I'm surprised you haven't seen any signs saying, "close" as I assume you've been to Japan where they are everywhere. I thought it was a Japanese-English thing, but then I also saw a "Path Close" construction sign in London...

Comment: can we say that "close" and "closed" are two completely different adjectives which happen to have a similar form?