# Why the opposite of "it's open" is "it's closed" rather than "it's close"?

Tags: adjectives

Why the opposite of "it's **open**" is "it's close**d**" rather than "it's close"?

Why there is not consistency in using this passive voice "ed" also for open, (i.g. open**ed**) or alternatively saying "it is close" without that additional "ed"?

In other words I would expect to have "open and close" or "opened and closed", but it is not consistent.

Dictionary: 
[close](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/close), [closed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/closed), [open](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open?q=opened).

Comment: If you're asking which to use, see *[Close Vs Closed and Open Vs. Opened](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15373/close-vs-closed-and-open-vs-opened)* If you're asking why, you should ask on [English.SE], though the inverse of this question was already asked at *[Opened vs open?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141547)*

Comment: One of the closest things to consistency in English is that so few things are consistent.